# from C to assembly

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly

how can I get assembly code from C program I used this [recommendation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html)
and I use something like this `-c -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -S` in Eclipse, but I've got an error, thanks in advance for any help

now I have this error

```
   atam.c:11: error: conflicting types for 'select'
/usr/include/sys/select.h:112: error: previous declaration of 'select' was here
atam.c:11: error: conflicting types for 'select'
/usr/include/sys/select.h:112: error: previous declaration of 'select' was here
```

this my function

```
int select(int board[],int length,int search){
    int left=0, right=length-1;

    while(1){
        int pivot_index=(right+left)/2;
        int ordered_pivot=partition(board,left,right,pivot_index);

        if(ordered_pivot==search){
            return board[ordered_pivot];
        }
        else if(search<ordered_pivot){
            right=ordered_pivot-1;
        }
        else{
            left=ordered_pivot+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse isn't a C compiler, but I'm guessing you're using GCC as the backend, so `-S` should be sufficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is still treating the output as an object file

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -S -oatam.o ..\atam.c
```

is generating assembly like you want, but confusingly storing it in `atam.o` because of the `-oatam.o` passed to GCC (normally you would store assembly in `atam.s`). The next command:

```
gcc -oatam.exe atam.o
```

Attempts to link `atam.o` and generate an executable, but `atam.o` is an assembly source, not an object file, so the linker fails. You need to tell eclipse not to run the second command (and you probably want to change the output filename of the first)

Comment: sorry, but what exactly have I enter?

Comment: @lego `gcc -S ..\atam.c` is all you strictly need; that will generate an assembly file named `atam.s`

Answer (score 2):

The error is happening because select is a Unix system call and your definition is clashing with the declaration in the relevant system header.  You need to rename your function.

Comment: I was completely confused what you were talking about until I looked at the revision history; he apparently edited the question to say something completely different from the original question, and then edited again after you answered to take out most of the information, including all references to `select()`. I rolled it back since this appears to be the answer he's looking for

Answer (score 1):

`-S` instructs the compiler to not go through with the actual compilation and linking step and stop after emitting the assembly. On the other hand you're also telling the compiler to compile your file on the same line (in addition to other conflicting settings).

Try this:

```
gcc -O0 -S ../atam.c
```

Optimizations will take the assembly file generated farther away from your source code, so I instructed gcc to turn off optimizations. Also don't run the linker.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never helpful. What error are you getting when you run that from the command line?